# Google play games services - Achievement point

Tags: android, google-play-games

Is there a way to get the [point value](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/achievements#points) of an Google Play Games achievement in my app?

I can't find anything in the [API:s](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/achievement/Achievement.html).

I want to create an achievement-leaderboard, without having to have the achievement values in two different places (the game and the games services console).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, unfortunately we don't currently provide a way to retrieve the point value of an achievement programatically. It's a good feature request, though!

Answer (score -2):

You need to call loadAchievements from your gamesClient like this:

```
gamesClient.loadAchievements(new OnAchievementsLoadedListener(){

            @Override
            public void onAchievementsLoaded(int statusCode,
                    AchievementBuffer buffer) {

                    for(Achievement a : buffer){
                          Log.i("State:"+a.getState());

                    }


        });
```

this will print out if the Achievement is solved or not (or if its incremental) you can also get, how many incremental steps are already solved with

```
     a.getCurrentSteps();
```

Read more about Achievements [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/achievement/Achievement.html)

Comment: Thank you, but this is not what I am looking for. You are referring to incremental achievements value https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/achievements#incremental_achievements . I need information about the achievement point value https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/achievements#points